# HTML: Text won't center (<div>)

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website for our Roblox group

I am trying to center this text (and the button below), but it looks off...
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hihZB.png)

It "centers" but it just looks not, I tried searching everywhere but nothing helps

The text code:

```html
<div style="font-family: 'Algerian'; color: #000000; font-size: 1150%; position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 10%">EUROPA</div>
```

Comment: <div style="font-family: 'Algerian'; color: #000000; font-size: 1150%;text-align: center;">EUROPA</div>

Comment: Please try this

Comment: And you can also use     "transform: translate(-50%, -50%);"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `transform:translate(-50%,-50%);` to you code

Answer (score -1):

Add `transform: translateX(-50%);`.
This should center **EUROPA** horizontally.

Comment: **This answer is extremely similar to the one provided by [Junaid Shaikh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17033432/junaid-shaikh), posted 6 minutes before your answer.**

Comment: @Junaid Shaikh's solution would _center_ the `div` both vertically and horizontally(not something what @nin wants), hence I provided a way to _center_ the `div` only horizontally.
Secondly, I don't have the privilege of commenting, otherwise I would have corrected him in the comments.

Answer (score -1):

Try to do every styling in css externally
if u want the button at the middle of the page
try justify-content: center
and align-item:center
i am not that good in css but try both ig

Comment: **Tip #1: _To improve your answer, consider using code blocks or inline code tags_.**

Comment: **Tip #2: _Use correct capitalization, punctuation, and sentence structure. Doing so will make your answer easier to read and comprehend_.**